# Ternary operator not changing state

Tags: flutter, conditional-operator, flutter-getx

There is a text displaying the scheduled time, Basically, the color of the text should change depending on the time, so if the scheduled time is in the future then it should not change its color and if it's in the past then its color should change to red. The scheduled time is when the notification should appear and when the notification appears it should change, the ternary operation works properly but only when I click another widget to change its state, it does not change the state on its own. I am using getx so I also tried Obx but that didn't work. How can I resolve this?

```
                 Visibility(
                            visible: todoController.todos[index].date ==
                                        '' &&
                                    todoController.todos[index].time == ''
                                ? false
                                : true,
                            child: Obx(() => Text(
                                (todoController.todos[index].date != now)
                                    ? '${todoController.todos[index].date!}, ${todoController.todos[index].time}'
                                    : 'Today, ${todoController.todos[index].time}',
                                style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
                                  color: (run(
                                                  todoController
                                                      .todos[index].date,
                                                  todoController
                                                      .todos[index].time)
                                              .compareTo(tz.TZDateTime.now(
                                                  tz.local)) >
                                          0)
                                      ? Theme.of(context).hintColor
                                      : Colors.redAccent,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  decoration:
                                      (todoController.todos[index].done)
                                          ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                          : TextDecoration.none,
                                ))),
                          )
```

TodoController:

```
class TodoController extends GetxController {
 var todos = <Todo>[].obs;

 @override
 void onInit() {
  List? storedTodos = GetStorage().read<List>('todos');

if (storedTodos != null) {
  todos = storedTodos.map((e) => Todo.fromJson(e)).toList().obs;
}
ever(todos, (_) {
  GetStorage().write('todos', todos.toList());
});
super.onInit();
}}
```

Comment: Please provide controller code also for better understanding

Comment: I am using getx

Comment: did you wrap your widget with `Obx`?

Comment: Yes but that didn't work

Comment: Show us how you wrapped your widget with `Obx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `Obx` widget up and wrap the `Visibility` widget with it:

```
Obx(()=> Visibility(....));
```

**Update**

You have problem with this line:

```
todos = storedTodos.map((e) => Todo.fromJson(e)).toList().obs;
```

Instead of re-assigning the Rx variable itself, you should assign the data to the Rx variables value:

```
todos.assignAll(storedTodos.map((e) => Todo.fromJson(e)).toList());
```

Comment: Still doesn’t work

Comment: Verify that your ternary produces expected results.

Comment: It works as expected, but the only problem is it does not change state, Only when I press another widget to change the state, it changes its state

Comment: Got it! Check the updated answer.